# What does the "overworld_caves" dimension type do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

`minecraft:overworld_caves` is [one of the preset dimension types](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Custom_dimension#Syntax_2). However, being down in the cave layer seems to use the `minecraft:overworld` behavior.

What does `minecraft:overworld_caves` do?

Comment: Because its one of the dimension_types alongside the overworld, the_nether, and the_end